# SQL Server wont start on my 64-bit virtualization slice

Tags: sql-server, virtualization, 64-bit

I have installed SQL server 2008 express on a 64-bit virtual box and the service wont start.

Looking at the event log I get:

> Could not create tempdb. You may not
>   have enough disk space available. Free
>   additional disk space by deleting
>   other files on the tempdb drive and
>   then restart SQL Server. Check for
>   additional errors in the event log
>   that may indicate why the tempdb files
>   could not be initialized.
>
> For more information, see Help and
>   Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

And also:

> FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating
>   system error 2(failed to retrieve text
>   for this error. Reason: 1815) occurred
>   while creating or opening file
>   'e:\sql10_main_t\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBLog.ldf'.
>   Diagnose and correct the operating
>   system error, and retry the operation.

Note: Theres another error like this for the mdf file too.

Now what is odd is that there is no e drive mapped to this box so I dont know why this is trying to open a file from here. Don't know if this is something to do with the fact that is a virtual slice and maybe the host machine has this drive mapped?

Any advise welcome.

Chris.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (Be aware I did this on 2005 Express so you may have to adjust as required):

Open up a console and try to start in single user mode:

```
sqlsvr.exe -m -s <instance_name>
```

If it starts you can now open up management studio and try the following:

```
-- alter the database
ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE ( NAME = 'tempdev', FILENAME = 'SomeWhere\Here\tempdb.mdf' )
ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE ( NAME = 'templog', FILENAME = 'SomeWhere\Here\templog.ldf' )

-- ensure that it has been moved
SELECT name, physical_name as CurrentLocation, state_desc
from sys.master_files
WHERE database_id IN (DB_ID('tempdev'), DB_ID('templog')
```

Now stop sql server and try to restart from the services console. It *should* successfully start now.

If it does also do the following to ensure new databases are created in the proper locations:

1. Open **Management Studio Express** and login
2. **Right Click your server** and select Properties
3. Click **Database Settings**
4. Change default **Database Locations** to what is on your VPS

This should change the default locations

Comment: sqlsvr.exe isnt in my path variables, where is this exe I cant find it.

Comment: Should be where it was installed into say something like: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn. You could try a file system search in C:\Program Files

Comment: No file there, but in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn there is a "sqlservr.exe". Though this just brings up an empty prompt box. Any ideas?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlsvr.exe -m -s <instance_name> if the command prompt stays open it is running. You can then connect with management studio express and run the above TSQL commands

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you...

In order to resolve this you have to rebuild the database using this command string below. 
This command MUST be run from this directory.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Release

Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=accounts /[SAPWD= StrongPassword]

If you are using Windows authentication you can ditch the strong password portion of the command like so.

Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=accounts

You can read more on the issue at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx. Hope this can help somebody out.