# Cannot install SQL 2008 RC2

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008

I can't run SQL server after installing it.

Its looking in `e:`, but I do not have an e-drive. I have tried resetting my registry key as shown [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/ba3eca90-e436-408e-a44c-527a66edb8fc/) all the answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/86537/sql-server-wont-start-on-my-64-bit-virtualization-slice)

Log file:

```
2011-05-19 21:22:39.63 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2011-05-19 21:22:39.63 Server      Detected 16 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2011-05-19 21:22:39.65 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2011-05-19 21:22:39.65 Server      Lock partitioning is enabled.  This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2011-05-19 21:22:39.70 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0 Active CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2011-05-19 21:22:39.73 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.
2011-05-19 21:22:39.80 spid7s      2 transactions rolled forward in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2011-05-19 21:22:39.80 spid7s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2011-05-19 21:22:39.80 spid7s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2011-05-19 21:22:39.85 spid7s      FILESTREAM: effective level = 0, configured level = 0, file system access share name = 'EXP'.
2011-05-19 21:22:39.86 spid7s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2011-05-19 21:22:39.86 spid7s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2011-05-19 21:22:39.88 spid7s      The resource database build version is 10.50.1600. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2011-05-19 21:22:39.99 spid7s      Server name is 'CT4417\EXP'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2011-05-19 21:22:39.99 spid10s     Starting up database 'model'.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid10s     Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid10s     FCB::Open failed: Could not open file e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\model.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid7s      Informational: No full-text supported languages found.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid10s     Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid10s     Unable to open the physical file "e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\model.mdf". Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path specified.)".
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid7s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid10s     Error: 17207, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid10s     FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file 'e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\modellog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid7s      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid7s      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBData.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid10s     File activation failure. The physical file name "e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\modellog.ldf" may be incorrect.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid7s      Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid7s      Unable to open the physical file "e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBData.mdf". Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path specified.)".
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid10s     Error: 945, Severity: 14, State: 2.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid10s     Database 'model' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.  See the SQL Server errorlog for details.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid10s     Could not create tempdb. You may not have enough disk space available. Free additional disk space by deleting other files on the tempdb drive and then restart SQL Server. Check for additional errors in the event log that may indicate why the tempdb files could not be initialized.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid10s     SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid7s      Error: 17207, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid7s      FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file 'e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBLog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.
2011-05-19 21:22:40.00 spid7s      File activation failure. The physical file name "e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBLog.ldf" may be incorrect.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First choice: Reinstall.

If you really must try and save it: Load up SQL Server configuration manager. Find the service under SQL Server Services, right click for Properties, and change the file locations under the Advanced. This may or may not work.

Comment: I already tried uninstalled and reinstall 3 times, than I tried everything here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/ed4514fa-8d1d-4383-bbdf-fb06bfbad106/  then uninstall reinstall again and it now works. I have no idea why. But it works =)

Answer (score 1):

After five hours, I can start the new SQL Server Instance. Follow this steps:

**1. Start the engine:**

```
NET START MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS /f /T3608
```

**2. Check that the paths are invalid:**
    SELECT name, physical_name, state_desc FROM sys.master_files ORDER BY database_id;
    GO

**3. Alter the paths**
ALTER DATABASE model MODIFY FILE ( NAME = modeldev, FILENAME = 'C:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\model.mdf');
ALTER DATABASE model MODIFY FILE ( NAME = modellog, FILENAME = 'C:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf');

ALTER DATABASE msdb MODIFY FILE ( NAME = MSDBData, FILENAME = 'C:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\MSDBData.mdf');
ALTER DATABASE msdb MODIFY FILE ( NAME = MSDBLog, FILENAME = 'C:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\MSDBLog.ldf');

ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE ( NAME = tempdev, FILENAME = 'C:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\temp.mdf');
ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE ( NAME = templog, FILENAME = 'C:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\temp.ldf');

GO

**4. Exit:**

exit;

**5. Stop de engine:**

NET STOP MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS

Ready!!! Now start the engine normally.